# Sign into a 3rd party website using Postman or Curl: Learning experience

Tags: javascript, forms, curl, cookies, postman

I am trying to understand a how form submits work. Currently, I am signing on to this site: [Work website](https://websandsexpo.celayix.com/sandsexpo/login.asp) What I would like to do is use [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) or `curl` to sign in.

> In the form is see 4 possible keys: `Username`, `Password`, `ClientID` and
> `Remember`.

- I am submitting each one of these with Postman and I am getting
  `Invalid Login` error.
- I am guessing this is because Postman does not set up the cookies like in MM_validateForm()

Can anyone help me solve this? If it is because of the cookies, is there a way to set this with Postman? Perhaps in the `header` keys and values area?

Here is all the inputs of the form:

```
<form 
action="login-process.asp" 
method="post" 
name="form1" 
id="form1" onsubmit="MM_validateForm('ClientID','','R','Username','','R','Password','','R');return document.MM_returnValue">
```

...

```
<input 
name="ClientID" 
type="hidden" 
id="ClientID" 
value="LVSandsExpoCC">
```

...

```
<input 
name="Username" 
type="text" 
id="Username"
value="">
```

...

```
<input 
name="Password" 
type="password"
id="Password">
```

...

```
<input 
type="submit" 
name="Submit" 
value="Submit">
```

The MM_validateForm() (after validates it updates the cookies)

```
 var myDate = new Date();
    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 365);
    if (document.getElementById("Remember").checked) {
      jaaulde.utils.cookies.set("CelayixRemember", encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("ClientID").value + "|" + document.getElementById("Username").value), {
        secure: true,
        expiresAt: myDate
      });
    } else {
      jaaulde.utils.cookies.set("CelayixRemember", "", {
        secure: true,
        expiresAt: myDate
      });
    }
    setClientPath();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this has to do with the `ASPSESSIONIDASBUBTDA` cookie. This is what Chrome sends when I try to login on the page you mentioned:
([image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5ZhL.png))

You'll need to retrieve your value using Chrome and use it when making a request with Postman or CURL.

So, a CURL command should look like this:

```
curl "https://websandsexpo.celayix.com/sandsexpo/login-process.asp"
--data "ClientID=LVSandsExpoCC&Username=<username>&Password=<password>&Submit=Submit"
--cookie "ASPSESSIONIDASBUBTDA=<value>" --cookie-jar ./cjar --compressed -L
```

`-L` in the command above ensures that CURL follows the redirection if it is set in the `Location` header. `--cookie-jar` saves your cookies in a file so you can reuse them in future requests.

In Postman, I suppose, the cookie should be set as a request header explicitly.

P.S. I strongly doubt the `MM_validateForm()` function is any relevant here, as it only handles the cookie expiration date.

Comment: Nice use with curl. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out for Postman, my problem was this:

I was using `Postman` to send `form-data` but when viewing the dev tools `network` tab I see that the content type is `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

[image: x-www-form-url-encoded example picture]

In `Postman` you have this option to send in the body `form-data` as well as `x-www-form-urlencoded`. I had form-data selected which is why it did not authenticate.

[image: Postman example showing options]

As far as `MM_validateForm()`, I disabled Javascript and was still able to log in. So it seems this was not the reason for my failed login in this case.

as the user `makeiteasy` said,

> P.S. I strongly doubt the MM_validateForm() function is any relevant
>   here, as it only handles the cookie expiration date. - `makeiteasy` (Stackoverflow user)

and this is very true.